# How to include Jword and Jspreadsheet in a same project

Tags: android, gradle

I'm not able to include `jword.jar` and `jspreadsheet.jar` in Android project as both libs contain some named classes and packages files.

I tried the code below but it didn't work for me..

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
}
```

Can anyone help me to figure it out?